# Find a row that has passed different steps in the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi to all here it is my problem:

I have an history table where a record register different steps:

| Id | Step | Item Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Created | 112345 |
| 2 | Approved | 112345 |
| 3 | Completed | 112345 |
| 4 | Closed | 112345 |
| 5 | Created | 112346 |
| 6 | Approved | 112346 |
| 8 | Closed | 112346 |

What i want to find inside this table is:

All the item codes that have done one step (for example the Approved one) and where the next one is not the "natural one" (for expample the Completed one). In the example table the time code 112346 item has done the Approved step but has skipped the Completed step).

Is there anyway to do a query like this? I've used the PARTITION BY to make a cluster of Item ,for each step, but i am unable to continue the query.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestion

Comment: and which result you expect all item code that have not 4 steps? or are3 missinfg completed?

Comment: Create  a table of step names with a proper ordering int column and use `lag()` to detect missing steps.

Comment: @nbk all i need is the item codes that "consequentially" hasen't pass a particular value but have skipped it. For example all the request that has at time n-1 was in the status Approved but in the time n are not in the status Completed

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `LEAD` analytic function to check if the next step is not the expected one:

```sql
SELECT id, step, item_code
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         LEAD(step) OVER (PARTITION BY item_code ORDER BY id) AS next_step
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE step = 'Approved'
AND   (next_step IS NULL OR next_step != 'Completed')
```

Or, from Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to perform row-by-row processing:

```sql
SELECT id, step, item_code
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY item_code
  ORDER     BY id
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN ( approved {- (not_completed|$) -} )
  DEFINE
    approved      AS step = 'Approved',
    not_completed AS step <> 'Completed'
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Id, Step, Item_Code) AS
SELECT 1, 'Created',   112345 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Approved',  112345 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Completed', 112345 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Closed',    112345 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Created',   112346 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'Approved',  112346 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 'Closed',    112346 FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | ID | STEP | ITEM_CODE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 6 | Approved | 112346 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=85a75ff807188f642c06a2bf433b328f)*

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have a table of step names with a proper ordering int column (`seqno`)

```
with 
/* Sample data */
steps(seqno, Step) as (
   select 1, 'Created'   from dual union all
   select 2, 'Approved'  from dual union all
   select 3, 'Completed' from dual union all
   select 4, 'Closed'    from dual 
),
tbl(Id, Step, ItemCode) as (  
   select 1, 'Created'  , 112345 from dual union all
   select 2, 'Approved' , 112345 from dual union all
   select 3, 'Completed', 112345 from dual union all
   select 4, 'Closed'   , 112345 from dual union all
   select 5, 'Created'  , 112346 from dual union all
   select 6, 'Approved' , 112346 from dual union all
   select 8, 'Closed'   , 112346 from dual 
),
/* Find steps with the next step being out of order */
m as (
  select max(seqno)+1 term
  from steps
)
select Id, Step, ItemCode
from (
  SELECT t.*, s.seqno, lead(s.seqno, 1, (select term from m)) over(partition by ItemCode order by Id) nextSeqno
  FROM tbl t
  JOIN steps s on s.Step = t.Step
) q
cross join m
where nextseqno != Seqno + 1 and nextseqno < m.term
```